how can I take the % of EV in the fuel_type_1 column against all other fuel types?
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fuel_type_1 = 'Electricity' THEN 1 END) AS electricity_count,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN fuel_type_1 = 'Electricity' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS electric_percentage
FROM 
    fuel$

this is the code I have and I would like to get to the percent of Electric cars in my dataset against all other fuel types, however, the returned value is just 0.
this is the query result I get:
electricity_count   total_count electric_percentage
133                  38080              0

here is the sample data


Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Hey!  I just added sample data screenshot

Please replace images with formatted text, just enough to qualify as minimally reproducible. Do this for both sample data and desired output.

Added casting to the query you wrote.. this will give you the correct % value
select cast (electricity_count as decimal)/ cast (total_count as decimal) *100 as electric_percentage from (
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN fuel_type_1 = 'Electricity' THEN 1 END) AS electricity_count,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count
   FROM 
    fuel$ ) a

